# Transfer the array indexing, would like to increment just the index of array data in to another array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, arraylist

I have an bash script with an array like that..

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A data
declare -A dataindex

data[food0]='pasta'
data[food1]='orange'
data[drink0]='water'
data[drink1]='juice'

for ((i=0;i<=${#data[@]};i++))
do
$dataindex[$i]=${!data}
done

echo dataindex
```

I would like to increment just the index of array data in to another array.

That's a simplified way to represent one part of my project, i'm developing a method to filter values based on array indexing, i develop some logic methods to do that... if someone knows some thing about that i will be greatfull.

Expected output

```
food0 food1 drink0 drink1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what "I would like to increment just the index of array data in to another array." means and show concise, testable sample input and expected output when that occurs.

Comment: According to which rule should `dataindex[n]` be associated with a certain string inside the associative array `data`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you shouldn't be using shell arrays for that and instead should be using a text processing tool like awk.

I couldn't figure out what exactly you were trying to do in your code or what you wanted to do so here's an awk script called within a shell script that just prints the index and associated value from the array so you can do whatever you like with them:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        data["food0"]  = "pasta"
        data["food1"]  = "orange"
        data["drink0"] = "water"
        data["drink1"] = "juice"

        for ( idx in data ) {
            val = data[idx]
            print "idx=" idx, "val=" val
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
idx=drink0 val=water
idx=drink1 val=juice
idx=food0 val=pasta
idx=food1 val=orange
```

Consider also other possibilities for doing whatever it is you're to do with array indices and values, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("food0 food1 drink0 drink1",idxs)
        split("pasta orange water juice",vals)
        for ( i in idxs ) {
            idx = idxs[i]
            val = vals[i]
            data[idx] = val
        }

        for ( i in idxs ) {
            printf "idxs[%s]=%s\n", i, idxs[i]
        }

        print ""

        for ( i in vals ) {
            printf "vals[%s]=%s\n", i, vals[i]
        }

        print ""

        for ( idx in data ) {
            printf "data[%s]=%s\n", idx, data[idx]
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
idxs[1]=food0
idxs[2]=food1
idxs[3]=drink0
idxs[4]=drink1

vals[1]=pasta
vals[2]=orange
vals[3]=water
vals[4]=juice

data[drink0]=water
data[drink1]=juice
data[food0]=pasta
data[food1]=orange
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, it's a one-liner:

```bash
declare -a dataindex=( "${!data[@]}" )
```

Examining the variables:

```bash
$ declare -p data dataindex
declare -A data=([drink1]="juice" [drink0]="water" [food1]="orange" [food0]="pasta" )
declare -a dataindex=([0]="drink1" [1]="drink0" [2]="food1" [3]="food0")
```

Note the order of the indexes: associative arrays are unordered.

Answer (score -3):

Solved, change the for....

```
for i in ${!data[@]}; do
dataindex=$i
done
```

Comment: this doesn't create an array; this repeatedly overwrites the value in the variable `dataindex`; after the `for` loop add `typteset -p dataindex` to see what it contains

Comment: this just put the index of data array in another array content... that's i wanted